# How do I correctly update values with a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have a `Products` table with columns `QtySold_Day` and `QtySold_Yesterday`, which contain information about the quantity of sold products today and yesterday respectively.

I want to create a trigger that moves every single value from the `QtySold_Day` column to the `QtySold_Yesterday` whenever there's an attempt to update the `QtySold_Day` column.

This is what I already have:

```
create or alter trigger UpdateQuantity 
on Products
instead of update
as
    declare @x int
    set nocount on

    while (@x < @@ROWCOUNT)
    begin
        update Products 
        set QtySold_Day = QtySold_Yesterday 
        where (ProductID = @x)
    end
```

I'd like to know how can I finish the trigger for it to work as intended.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: So if you happen to update the value of `QtySold_Day` three times in one day, you would assign the current value to `QtySold_Yesterday` three times? Seems like a **really horribly bad idea** to do this! These values should be **calculated** as and when needed - not stored and shoved around with a trigger.....

Answer (score 0):

1. SQL is a set based language, so you should always attempt set based operations. Inside a trigger you have access to a pseudo table called `Inserted` which has the new details of the update. You can therefore update all the relevant records in one go.
2. As commented you are probably going to need a way to avoid copying the values over if the record is updated multiple times - so I have added a check to ensure it only happens once. That might not be quite the behaviour you want so if you clarify we can tweak it.
3. Do you really want an `INSTEAD OF` trigger? Because that will capture **ALL** updates to this table, and for the most part do nothing.

```
UPDATE Products SET
    QtySold_Day = QtySold_Yesterday 
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
-- Only update once
AND QtySold_Yesterday IS NULL;
```